# PooledConnection has already been closed

Tags: grails, groovy, transactions, grails3

I have a grails 3.1.12 application and using Oracle DB. I am getting "PooledConnection has already been closed" exception while running the following code snippet1 and code snippet2. Snippet 1 and Snippet 2 works and intermittently gives PooledConnection closed exception. Some of the stackoverflow links suggested changing datasource type to c3P0 solved the issue but this doesn't work for me. I am trying to understand what is causing this issue , any suggestions how to resolve this issue ?

**Snippet1 :**

```
    class HistoryService {
static transactional = false
def manualHistoryLog(def originalObject, def newObject, def mode, def simpleName, def objectId, def refObject){
//.............//
addObject(newObject, false)
}
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public addObject(def newObject, def booleanVal)
{
    try {  
            log.info("Start of solrIndexService.addObject")         
            solrIndexService.addObject(newObject, booleanVal)
            log.info("End of solrIndexService.addObject")   
    }
    catch(e) {
        log.error("error adding object", e)
    }
}
}
```

**Please note that I recently added @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in above method addObject() but still no luck and getting Pooled closed connection exception.**

**Snippet 2 :**

```
    class ActionLogService {
def saveActionLog(def actionLog,def eventName,def saveToSolr) {
                try{
                    log.debug( "Solr Indexing :::: START")
                    solrIndexService.addObjectFetch(actionLog, false)
                    log.debug( "Solr Indexing :::: END")
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error ("IO error thrown while indexing", e)
                }catch(Exception e){
                    log.error ("error thrown while indexing", e)
                }
}
}
```

**### Environment Information**

- Operating System: Windows 7
- Grails Version: 3.1.12
- JDK Version: 1.8

DataSource configured in application.groovy :

```
dataSource {
dbCreate = 'None'
pooled = true
dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
type = "javax.sql.DataSource" //required
auth = "Container" // optional
description = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
username = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
password = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
properties
{
maxActive = "25"
maxIdle = "25"
maxWait: "3000"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = "60000"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = "60000"
}
}
```

**Full Stack trace for Pooled connection closed exception :**

```
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:14,958][AuditUpdateThread        ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] Solr Indexing :::: START
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:14,974][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] Solr Indexing :::: START
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:15,445][AuditUpdateThread        ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] Solr Indexing :::: END
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:15,445][AuditUpdateThread        ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] SAVED ACTION LOG
[ERROR][2016-12-07 14:49:15,549][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] error thrown while indexing
org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
        at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:183)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:484)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.SolrIndexService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66742596.addObjectFetch(<generated>)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.SolrIndexService$addObjectFetch.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at com.xms.logAction.ActionLogService$_closure1.doCall(ActionLogService.groovy:791)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:923)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:906)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeClosure(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:574)
        at com.xms.logAction.ActionLogService.logChanges(ActionLogService.groovy:770)
        at com.xms.logAction.ActionLogService$logChanges.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService.manualHistoryLog(HistoryService.groovy:365)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService$manualHistoryLog$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService.manualHistoryLog(HistoryService.groovy:393)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService$manualHistoryLog$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService.manualHistoryLog(HistoryService.groovy:343)
        at com.xms.core.searchServices.HistoryService$manualHistoryLog.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at com.xms.core.order.job.CandidateSubmissionController.submitSubmissionToClient(CandidateSubmissionController.groovy:2453)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at com.xms.core.order.job.CandidateSubmissionController.submitToClient(CandidateSubmissionController.groovy:2463)
        at com.xms.core.order.job.CandidateSubmissionController.submitToClient(CandidateSubmissionController.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:588)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.grails.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:73)
        at org.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:156)
        ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584)
        ... 148 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
        ... 149 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.commit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor808.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.commit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor808.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.commit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor808.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.commit(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
        ... 150 common frames omitted
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:15,553][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.l.ActionLogService] SAVED ACTION LOG
[INFO ][2016-12-07 14:49:15,553][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.HistoryService] Before calling addObject :: newObject ::com.xms.core.order.job.CandidateSubmission : 18894
[INFO ][2016-12-07 14:49:15,659][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.HistoryService] Start of solrIndexService.addObject
[DEBUG][2016-12-07 14:49:15,860][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.SolrIndexService] SOLR INDEXING xmsId: 18894, objectType: 105, curType: CandidateSubmission
[INFO ][2016-12-07 14:49:17,698][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.SolrIndexService] SOLR INDEXING finished building object 105.18894
[INFO ][2016-12-07 14:49:17,904][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.HistoryService] End of solrIndexService.addObject
[INFO ][2016-12-07 14:49:17,922][http-nio-8080-exec-5     ][g.a.s.c.x.c.s.HistoryService]
```

**NOTE :** solrIndexService does not have any transactional property defined . I tried to put @Transactional property at the class level for HistoryService, ActionLogService, SolrIndexService but the Solr search in application was failing with below 500 error. So I have to revert the code.

```
Error executing tag <g:form>: [views/advancedSearch/_listTileOuter.gsp:22] Error executing tag <g:render>: No transactionManager was specified. Using @Transactional or @Rollback requires a valid configured transaction manager.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this exception when pass the connection as parameter to a function **in a new thread**.
My solution was to pass the dataSource and instantiate a new connection inside the function.